# Style MenuItext color dynamically

Tags: java, android, menuitem, android-menu

is there a way to style the menu item text dynamically from a fragment? Like in the photo below, ideally I'd like to dynamically style settings whenever the corresponding fragment is fired up to whatever color I'd like without having to make a custom layout for a menu item.

[image]

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.suggestions_fragment, menu)
   MenuItem done = menu.findItem(R.id.done);
   SpannableString foo = new SpannableString("foo");
   spannableString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, spannableString.length(), 0);
   done.setTitle(spannableString);
```

}

Comment: Just use [ForegroundSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ForegroundColorSpan.html), and [SpannableString](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html).

Comment: Does not work when I set it up in oncreateoptionsmenu.

Comment: Have a look into this post :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21898745/android-change-option-menu-text-color?rq=1